# JscrollPane plugin is not display consistent in dialog jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have the issue with Jscrollpane plugin display inside the dialog jquery which have the table display.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      handleDialogOpenEvent();

       $("#dialog").dialog({
           resizable: true,          
           height: "300",     
           width: "400",    
           autoOpen: false,         
           modal: true,
           position: "center"

 });

    }

      function handleDialogOpenEvent(){
 $( "#dialog" ).bind( "dialogopen", function(event, ui) {
     $(".scrollpane").jScrollPane({'showArrows': true });


 });
```

}

I do not know how to correct the vertical scrollpane position to the right side of the table, the vertical scrollpane always display on top next to header of dialog and everytime dialog pop up the shape of dialog change eg: small height so I need to resize the dialog.

Comment: what is your html code